# Using DeferWindowPos to update z order?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to use DeferWindowPos to update the z order of some dialog boxes, but it's not working. Well, the z order does change, but not always in the requested order. Why could that be? It's supposed to work, right?

I am checking all the return values. I observered that if I add the flag SWP_NOSENDCHANGING, DeferWindowPos returns 0 without GetLastError() returning any error code. I didn't add message handlers for WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING in any of my dialog classes.

For now I use SetWindowPos instead. It always works but it's slower.

I wrote a test, see code below. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
void test()
{
#ifdef DEFER_WINDOW_POS
    class DeferPos
    {
    public:
        DeferPos( const int innWindowCount = 1 )
        {
            m_hdwp = BeginDeferWindowPos( innWindowCount );
            assert( m_hdwp != nullptr );
        }
        ~DeferPos()
        {
            if( !EndDeferWindowPos(m_hdwp) ) { assert( false ); }
        }

        void Set( HWND hWnd, HWND hWndAfter, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, UINT uFlags )
        {
            assert( m_hdwp != nullptr );
            assert( GetLastError() == 0 );

            m_hdwp = DeferWindowPos( m_hdwp, hWnd, hWndAfter, x, y, nWidth, nHeight, uFlags );

            assert( m_hdwp != nullptr );
            assert( GetLastError() == 0 );
        }

    private:
        HDWP m_hdwp = nullptr;
    };

    auto update_z_order = [](const std::vector<HWND>& vec, UINT flags)
    {       
        DeferPos dp( static_cast<int>(vec.size()) );
        HWND hWndAfter = HWND_TOP;
        for( HWND hWnd : vec )
        {
            dp.Set( hWnd, hWndAfter, 0, 0, 0, 0, flags );
            hWndAfter = hWnd;
        }
    };
#else
    auto update_z_order = [](const std::vector<HWND>& vec, UINT flags)
    {       
        HWND hWndAfter = HWND_TOP;
        for( HWND hWnd : vec )
        {
            ::SetWindowPos(hWnd, hWndAfter, 0, 0, 0, 0, flags );
            hWndAfter = hWnd;
        }
    };
#endif

    auto get_dialog_z_order = []()
    {
        std::vector<HWND> vec;
        EnumWindows( [](HWND hWnd, LPARAM lparam)-> BOOL
        {
            if( dynamic_cast<CDialog*>(CWnd::FromHandle(hWnd)) )
            {
                reinterpret_cast<std::vector<HWND>*>(lparam)->push_back( hWnd );
            }
            return TRUE;
        }, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&vec) );

        return vec;
    };

    const std::vector<HWND> original_order = get_dialog_z_order();
    const std::vector<HWND> reverse_order( original_order.rbegin(), original_order.rend() );

    const UINT flags = SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE;
    update_z_order( reverse_order, flags );

    const std::vector<HWND> new_order = get_dialog_z_order();

    assert( new_order == reverse_order ); // this assert sometimes fails when DEFER_WINDOW_POS is defined
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue: `assert( GetLastError() == 0 );` checks for pre- and postconditions, that aren't guaranteed ever. `GetLastError` returns a meaningful value only when the documentation says so. Unless `DeferWindowPos` fails, the return value of `GetLastError` is indeterminate.

Comment: Right, I understand that GetLastError as a pre-condition is not guaranteed and that the final check is only useful if the function fails. The only reason given by the documentation is insufficient system resources which seems unlikely. For this test I just wanted to be sure that there were no error codes flying.

BTW, I'd like to inspect the structure that the HDWP handle points to, but what data type is it? I did some searching but didn't find it.

Comment: That postcondition check will eventually produce false positives. An API call that succeeds is not required to reset the calling thread's last error code. It could well hold a transient error code, even if it succeeds. `HDWP` is an opaque handle. It is only useful to identify an internal structure used by the OS to store compound window placement information. I don't know whether this actually is a pointer to some structured data, and I couldn't find any information from the [ReactOS](https://github.com/reactos/reactos) implementation either.